# Elasticsearch: Should I increase the num of terms allowed, or do parallelization?

Tags: elasticsearch

Lately I've been getting constantly the following error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to create query: The number of terms [68746] used in the Terms Query request has exceeded the allowed maximum of [65536]. This maximum can be set by changing the [index.max_terms_count] index level setting.')
```

Until some days ago, since it was rare to get such an error, I would just parallelize my requests to the elasticserver, and move on. However, lately I've been dealing with more and more data.
I'm trying to understand whether I should in fact increase the `index.max_terms_count`  to a number like 1million, or if I should just continue to parallelize the requests...
In your experience, and with your knowledge, what would you recommend me to do?

Comment: Hi Mister SeaMan, this question is a bit opinion based. And it might need more details. Both direction are worth a try, although I would recommend taking a few step back on what you are doing and maybe find a 3rd way. As parallelism or increasing the limit is going to strain you Elasticsearch quickly.

Comment: @Paulo thanks for the comment... What more information would you like to know? I'm just starting out with Elasticsearch, and I'm using the python clients (dsl, and the low-level).